# How do I get more mech tech points?

Tags: battletech

It takes a long time for my mechs to be repaired between battles. How do I get more mech tech points to speed up repairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still on the starter dropship, you can't.  Once you get your next dropship, you can perform various upgrades to increase your mech tech points.